# no such table: FTSdictionary_content(table_name) in android

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I have a database which is in sdcard. I want to read that data from sdcard.

For that I have done below coding

```
    DbHelper helper = new DbHelper(this);
    SQLiteDatabase database = helper.getWritableDatabase();
    //in below line I am getting no such table error
    Cursor c = database.query(TestDataSource.TABLE_NAME, null, null, null, null, null, null);
    c.moveToFirst();
    do{
        System.out.println(c.getString(1));
    }while(c.moveToNext());
```

In DbHelper class also I have done below code:

```
    public class DbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "gujarati.db";
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
SQLiteDatabase mDatabase;

public DbHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase database) {
    System.out.println("On Create is called");
    String dir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath();
    File dbfile = new File(dir + File.separator + "gujarati.db");
    System.out.println("is file exits " + dbfile.isFile());
    mDatabase = SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(dbfile, null);
    Cursor ti = mDatabase.rawQuery(
            "PRAGMA table_info(FTSdictionary_content)", null);
    if (ti.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            System.out.println("col: " + ti.getString(1));
        } while (ti.moveToNext());
    }
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
}
}
```

onCreate is working fine. Also I am getting all column name of "FTSdictionary_content" table but at the time of cursor initilization I am getting an error.

Comment: try to give dynamically name of your table.

Comment: What is `TestDataSource.TABLE_NAME` set to?

Comment: how it will be possible?

Comment: it is FTSdictionary_content

Comment: @Szymon it is FTSdictionary_content

Comment: @Komal show me your code Aahir..